# Code for exif data of an image

Tags: image, api, metadata, exif

Is there any code for getting all exif data of an image?
I want all possible data that can be extraxted from an image file(which the user will upload on my webpage) like bitrate ,file owner and security details. Also,if there have been any comments added to the image,i want to get that too.
If an API exists to do these things for any file(video,text,image) then it will be really helpful.

Thank you,
Shubham

Comment: there is code here http://www.xequte.com/imageenforum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=1001

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)

example:

```
<?php
echo "test1.jpg:<br />\n";
$exif = exif_read_data('tests/test1.jpg', 'IFD0');
echo $exif===false ? "No header data found.<br />\n" : "Image contains headers<br />\n";

$exif = exif_read_data('tests/test2.jpg', 0, true);
echo "test2.jpg:<br />\n";
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```

or there is a [exif.js](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exif/exif.js) that will do it aswell

Comment: there is also a jquery plugin available here http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/jquery-exif-data-plugin.html